# Howto create a JSON from form values?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create JSOn from the dynamic form fields and values,

When the user submits, i want to display the json feed in #results

I have the following code snippet below:

```
<form id="myform" class="form-wd">
    ............
</form>
<div id="results"> </div>
</div>
```

```js
$('#myform-wiz').on('submit', function(ev) {
    //alert($(this).serialize());
    var data = $(this).serialize(); // -> The URL encoded form data
    $("#results").text(data);
    ev.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are interested in JSON.stringify ?

```
    data = $(this).serialize();
    json_data = JSON.stringify(data);
     $("#results").text(json_data);
```

Comment: is it also posible to get the form labels realted to each input fields?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, try out [jquery-json plugin](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/) and call .toJSON() method to serialize a javascript object, number, string, or array into JSON.

```
var thing = {plugin: 'jquery-json', version: 2.3};

var encoded = $.toJSON( thing );
// '{"plugin":"jquery-json","version":2.3}'
var name = $.evalJSON( encoded ).plugin;
// "jquery-json"
var version = $.evalJSON(encoded).version;
// 2.3
```